What Are the Upper and Lower Limits for Lean Mass Index (LMI) and Fat Mass Index (FMI)?
Question:
I’m trying to understand the typical ranges for Lean Mass Index (LMI) and Fat Mass Index (FMI) for both males and females. Based on some data I’ve gathered, the values are as follows:
For Males:
•   Minimum LMI: 12
•   Maximum LMI: 27
•   Minimum FMI: 1
•   Maximum FMI: 12

For Females:
•   Minimum LMI: 10
•   Maximum LMI: 23
•   Minimum FMI: 2.5
•   Maximum FMI: 15

Are these ranges accurate and reflective of healthy body composition standards? What are the generally accepted upper and lower limits for LMI and FMI for males and females? Any references to studies or official guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Tricky: what's typical, what's healthy? Min and max based on what, from where? These numbers should also change depending on age.
